# How to display single valued data in BoxWhiskerChart?

Tags: plotting, charts

```
$Version
(* 12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021) *)

data = <|"A" -> {40344, 30000, 30000}, "B" -> {82000, 85008}, "C" -> {98328}, "D" -> {45096, 41520, 42552}|>

BoxWhiskerChart[data, ChartLabels -> Placed[Style[#, Black] & /@ Keys@data, Above]]
```

[image]

There is just a single value for the key "C" so it is missing from the chart. Is there some way to display the label and e.g. a fence line or a plot marker at that value? Preferably not using `Show` to combine with `ListPlot`.

Comment: Maybe the other sample sizes of 2 and 3 are just for an example but if those are the actual sample sizes, then a Box and Whisker plot makes no sense for 2 and 3 data points just as much as id doesn't make sense for 1 data point.  In that case just showing the data points gives the user a better display of what the data says.  If the points overlap, just jitter them a bit.

Comment: @JimB Most keys have 10 - 50 values, some have only 1 or 2. Just the nature of the data I am working with.

Comment: Got it.  Then you are consistent with the comment of @whuber (one of the best) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194842/minimum-recommended-sample-size-for-boxplots-boxplots-for-different-sample-si.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hack:

```
data = <|"A" -> {40344, 30000, 30000}, "B" -> {82000, 85008}, 
   "C" -> {98328, 98328, 98328}, "D" -> {45096, 41520, 42552}|>;

BoxWhiskerChart[data, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[Style[#, Black] & /@ Keys@data, Above], 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0.1, 0.1}, {10000, 10000}}]
```

[image]

Comment: you can also do  `BoxWhiskerChart[ReplaceAll[{x_} :> {x, x}]@data,  ChartLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Above]] `  where `data` is as in OP's original example (+1)